# Convergence in Karhunen-Loeve expansion

Tags: stochastic-processes, fourier-series

Let $X_t$ be a stochastic process over $[a, b]$. with continuous autocovariance function $C(s, t)$. The Karhunen-Loeve expansion consists in representing $X_t$ as
$$
X(t) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} Z_i \, e_i(t), \qquad Z_i = \int_a^b X(t) \, e_i(t) \, dt.
$$
where $e_i$ is an orthonormal basis of $L^2(a, b)$ given by Mercer's theorem. My question is: without using Mercer's theorem, what can we say **a priori** on the type of convergence of the previous equation?

My reasoning is the following: since $\mathbb E(X_t^2)$ is bounded from above uniformly in time by assumption, then using Fubini
$$
\mathbb E \int_a^b X_t^2 \, dt = \int_a^b \mathbb E(X_t^2) \, dt < \infty,
$$
and so, almost surely, the paths of $X$ are in $L^2(a, b)$. It therefore seems to me that the convergence above should be in $L^2(a, b)$ almost surely, i.e. almost surely
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i e_i \to X \quad \text{in $L^2(a, b)$ as $n \to \infty$}.
$$
Is this correct? I am wondering because in [this freely available paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.07526.pdf), it is claimed that the convergence is a priori in $L^2(\Omega \times (a, b))$.

Comment: You are right. We do have $L^{2}(a,b)$ convergence for almost all paths.

Comment: Many thanks! Do you also agree that it is not a priori clear that the convergence is in $L^2(\Omega \times (a, b))$. (Here $\Omega$ is the sample space.

Comment: Convergence also holds in $L^{2}(\Omega, (a,b))$.

Comment: Would you mind explaining why?

Comment: $(Z_ie_i)$ is an orthogonal  sequence in the product space. Compute the $L^{2}$ distance between $X(t)$ and the partial sums in the product space.

Comment: You need it to be a complete basis and not just a sequence, though, no?

Comment: Convergence of the  series in $L^{2}$ of the product space together with your observation of almost sure convergence in $L^{2}(a,b)$ show that $X(t)$ belongs to the closed subspace generated by this orthogonal system.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Oh, I'm starting to understand, thank you very much! I agree that in $\mathbb R$, if a function converges almost surely and in $L^2$, then the limit is the same, but in this more general setting I am not sure. If you have some time, would you mind writing this as an answer?

Comment: Or in fact I think I understand, now. Is this reasoning correct: the function $\|X - \sum_N Z-i e_i \|_{L^2(a, b)}$ converges both almost surely to 0 and in $L^2(\Omega)$ (by your observation). Hence the limit in $L^2(\Omega)$ coincides with the almost sure limit, and consequently $\|0 - \|X - \sum_N Z_i e_i\|_{L^2(a, b)}\|_{L^2(\Omega)}$ goes to zero. And then by Fubinin, the $L^2(\Omega)$ norm of the $L^2(a, b)$ norm is just the $L^2(\Omega \times [a, b])$ norm. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convergence in $L^{2}(a,b)$ for  almost all paths is correct.

Convergence in the norm of $L^{2} (\Omega \times (a,b))$ is also true. Since we already have convergence $L^{2}(a,b)$ for  almost all paths it is enough to prove convergence of the series $\sum Z_i e_i(t)$ in $L^{2} (\Omega \times (a,b))$. But $(Z_ie_i)$ is an orthogonal sequence in this space so we only have to check that $\sum \|Z_ie_i\|^{2} <\infty$. This last fact follows from the fact that $E\int_a^{b} |X(t)|^{2}dt <\infty$ and the way $Z_i$'s are constructed from the process: Recall that $Z_n=\int_a^{b}  X(t)e_n(t)dt$.

Comment: Is my comment above a correct understanding of why it is enough to prove the convergence of the series $\sum Z_i e_i$?

Comment: @RobertoRastapopoulos Yes,it is correct.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but could you elaborate on "This last fact follows..."?

Comment: @RobertoRastapopoulos I hope the last line I just added to my answer clears this point.

Comment: I think it does. Path wise $\sum_i Z_i^2 \leq \int_a^b X_t^2 \, dt$ almost surely by Bessel inequality. Therefore, swapping the expectation and the series $\sum_i \mathbb E (Z_i^2) \leq \mathbb E \int_a^b X_t^2 \, dt < \infty$. And then since $\mathbb E(Z_i^2) = \|Z_i e_i\|^2$, your claim follows. Is this it?

Comment: @RobertoRastapopoulos Yes, that is the argument.